# How to rewrite POSIX C code to use datagram socket instead of file

Tags: c, sockets, udp, posix

I have third-party C code that writes data to a file. I want to modify that code so it writes the exact same data to a datagram socket instead.

A pointer to `FILE` is handled over to the third-party code to determine which file to use. The data is written to the file exclusively using `fwrite()`.

Everything would be fine if the code would use `write()` instead of `fwrite()` because `write()` works on both sockets and files. It expects an integer as file descriptor which is the data type both `socket()` and `open()` return.

However, since the third-party code uses `fwrite()`, this task is not that easy. I wonder what would be the best way to get this task done.

Should I write a `fwrite()` function that does the same job as the original `fwrite()` using `write()` internally? Or is there a hack to "cast" an integer file descriptor to `FILE*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn a socket into a `FILE *` by using `fdopen`:

```
FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
```

I hope you are using a sequential datagram protocol (i.e., Unix datagram socket, not UDP socket), because otherwise, your data is going to get messed up.

**If you are using UDP:** The packets can be arbitrarily dropped or re-ordered, and since the code using the `FILE *` assumes that it's writing to disk, you'll get a big mess when you try to put everything together on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for the warning for using UDP. If I run into this problem, I might consider using TCP instead.

Comment: You **will** run into the problem, there is no way to prevent it except by using TCP (or writing your own reliable protocol on top of UDP).  Additionally, if the write buffer is too large the packets will *always* get dropped if you are using UDP.